# How to draw stacked part only of the barchart in a dashed (dotted) line using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to draw a horizontal stacked bar chart. What I need is to draw the stacked area of each bar in a dotted line. Also if it is possible I need to fill that stacked area with a transparent colour or dashed lines. All that is to show my stacked part of bars as possible improvements of the data I am showing on each bar.
I guess that can be achieved using a BarChartCustomRenderer but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not a part of the library. I had a similar case where I wanted the top of each stacked bar to be rounded and had to subclass BarChartRenderer to do it.

Comment: Thanks patrick-iv for your reply. Does it mean a BarChartRenderer can achieve it? If yes, can you give some hints. Another thing do you think it is possible to show extra icons or labels on the stacked area of each bar?

Comment: Hi, yes I'd say you would be able to achieve what you want by subclassing the BarChartRenderer. About adding icons and labels, that is possible as well, basically anything you can do with the Android Canvas API is possible to add. Unfortunately I can't share my rounded corner example since it was something I did at work, but the gist was basically just subclassing BarChartRenderer, overriding `drawDataSet(Canvas, IBarDataSet, Int)`, copying the code from the super class and modified it to my liking.

Comment: Thanks for hinting me out. That is quite useful.